# Avoid re-rendering images and other stuff from backbone views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

when I rerender a backbone view, what is a good way to skip re-rendering things like images and  google maps? My photo and map views tend to flicker really bad every time the view is re-rendered (which is quite often). With the images especially, it is the case that the templating engine is laying out the layout from scratch, which causes the image tags to fetch the bitmap either from the server or from the cache once again.

Of course, I still want the view to remain kind of agnostic of the layout, so technically it shouldn't know that we are going to display an image, right?

Comment: depends on how you are rendering the images? Are you using handlebars or just inserting them as text?

Comment: I am using mustache at this point, and simply insert the urls from the data model. I was thinking of jumping to handlebars at some point. Will this help?

Comment: Do you always re-compile your template?

Comment: I have similar problems. I am using Handlebars and only compile the template once. Whenever I re-render a template, the images flicker (no matter whether they are fetched from server or browser cache). It's quite annoying and the only workaround I found so far was to really only update the text parts that changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm gonna offer a solution that is in conflict with your assumption *"the View should be agnostic of the template"*.

If you call `render()` any time anything has changed in the Model you will have this *blinking* in your browser, especially if the *template* is big.

My recommendation is separate the `render` of the View which happens only once when the View is first time visualized and several `update` helper methods which are in charge of updating small pieces of the View linked to concrete Model attributes.

For example:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.on( "change:title", this.updateTitle, this );
    this.model.on( "change:description", this.updateDescription, this );
    // ... more change:XXX
  },

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
  },

  updateTitle: function(){
    this.$el.find( ".title" ).html( this.model.get( "title" ) );
  },

  updateDescription: function(){
    this.$el.find( ".description" ).html( this.model.get( "description" ) );
  },

  // ... more updateXXX()
})
```

Comment: that's true, and I've been following this approach for quite a while ... but more and more I started seeing the big names in the JS community advise for a clear separation of concerns ... although technically using templates in JS is still kinda flawed

Comment: @user1107412 there is always a constant tension between _patterns_ and _pragmatism_ :) (Pragmatism: _an approach that evaluates theories or beliefs in terms of the success of their practical application_ Oxford English Dictionary).

Comment: @user1107412: You could break the view into a set subviews and then let the little subviews update themselves as needed. That would probably be pointlessly pedantic unless a view was already too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

To get the best result you really don't want to re-render the HTML that contains your media so I would recommend using more targetted views for the content that changes so you don't need to re-render the views with content that doesn't.