# The use of backbone, and how to achieve two-way binding between the view and model ？

Tags: backbone.js

Specifically:

1.View the contents of the controls to change, automatically update the corresponding property in the model.

2.When a model within the property change, automatically updated view of this attribute corresponds to the control, rather than simply the call view.render () to re-update the entire view.

**Someone has a similar practice? Or any good resources to recommend, Thank you very much!**

Comment: The subject of your question is confusing. As I understand what you want is _"How to avoid re-render the whole View and re-render only small elements of it"_. If this is right, duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011129/avoid-re-rendering-images-and-other-stuff-from-backbone-views

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message.My poor English, the expression is not clear, my No.2 description is you say.

Comment: The No.1 is a very common patter, _View_ manipulates the _Model_'s state as its convenience. For No.2 follow the link I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actual what I want : https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder

The ModelBinder class contains all of the logic to facilitate **bi-directional view-model binding**.

: )

EDIT:20120715-----------
this is the perfect solution demo:
http://files.cnblogs.com/justinw/Nested_Model_bi_Binding.zip

Answer (score 3):

Rivets is another data-binding framework for Backbone and other JavaScript MV* frameworks like Spine. https://github.com/mikeric/rivets

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post illustrating two way data-binding between your Backbone views and models using the Backbone.ModelBinder plugin. Here is the direct link to the post : http://niki4810.github.io/blog/2013/03/02/new-post/